# Magento Adminhtml Font and Markup

Tags: admin, adminhtml, localisation, design

I want to customize the Magento admin with an stylish icon font (think Wingdings).

In **most cases** it's easy enough to do entirely via CSS with the `:before` pseudo-selector, outputting `content:` that is relevant and is styled with the aforementioned font.

But, in some cases, I don't just want to prepend an icon - I want the *entire text* to be in said font. My first thought is to do it via translation file:

**translate.csv:**

```
"CMS","<span class='iconify'>CMS</span>"
```

So - while this may work - it feels like a hack and I'm concerned that the markup would be used in places I don't intend it to be. I'd really like some feedback on alternate methods of accomplishing this. **Is there a better way?**

Comment: Instead of changing the translation files, why not override the `__()` method?

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the entire translation method to examine for 2 or 3 strings that I want to mark up...

Comment: oh...I misunderstood... I thought you want to add this for most of the texts.

Comment: The only right way to do it is to add `iconify` class to the template. Alternatively you can write a JavaScript which will do it.

Comment: If you're going to go the translation file route, make sure to leave easily found comments to let the next developer know what is going on. Aside from that, I would just change the templates directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no answers suggested something more elegant, the approach I took was to inject the tag markup via the translation file:

```
"CMS","<span class='iconify'>CMS</span>"
```